# Translate list of labels into array of labels per ID in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with texts and labels. Each text has multiple rows with on label.

```
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame([['Text1','label1'], ['Text1', 'label2']], columns=["TEXT", "LABELS"])
```

I would like to have the following to apply MultiLabelBinarizer() function.

```
TEXT | LABEL
Text1| [[label1,label2]]
```

[Reference 1](https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/one-hot-encoding-with-multiple-labels-in-python)
[Reference 2](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/66693)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need nested lists use lambda function in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = dummy_df.groupby('TEXT')['LABELS'].agg(lambda x: [x.tolist()]).reset_index()
print (df)
    TEXT              LABELS
0  Text1  [[label1, label2]]
```

Not nested lists:

```
df1 = dummy_df.groupby('TEXT')['LABELS'].agg(list).reset_index()
print (df1)
    TEXT            LABELS
0  Text1  [label1, label2]
```

Comment: Thank you! yes, the answers in the other post were confusing. your answer is easy to replicate and did the Job.